# Layout with relative width to current height

Tags: android, android-layout

Is it possible to have LinearLayout with layout_height="match_parent" and layout_width that would attribute to half the height?

I would then put those layouts in larger HorizontalScrollView and let layouts keep desired aspect ratio.

Is this possible without creating my own layout that would handle it ?

Comment: "and layout_width that would attribute to half the width", do you mean half the height?

Comment: half of the width, try use weights

Comment: @AbdallahAlaraby yes, thats a typo.

Comment: @deadfish I will be populating a large horizontal layout with these smaller layouts. The more layouts a put in it, the larger it gets. I don't know how weight would help me in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a custom ViewGroup for this. Google has one called [ProportionalLayout](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/ContactsCommon/+/master/src/com/android/contacts/common/widget/ProportionalLayout.java) -- it's not part of the Android SDK, so you have to copy the source code into your app in order to use it in your XML layouts.

You also need to add this to `res/values/attrs.xml`:

```
<declare-styleable name="ProportionalLayout">
    <attr name="direction" format="string"/>
    <attr name="ratio" format="float"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

Comment: I like your answer more than my own :D didn't know about that layout

Answer (score 0):

You can do that programmatically by getting the layout height and then set the width to half that size.

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.numberPadLayout);
int height = layout.getHeight();
LayoutParams params = layout.getLayoutParams();
params.height = height;
params.width = height/2;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced with this question month ago. The found the only way to solve it:
In the layout file make width = match_parent, and height = 0dp or whatever!

In the onCreate method add  of your activity add onGlobalLayoutListener(). This method will be called when all heights and widths of all widgets are measured. So you can get your width by mLinearLayout.getWidth();

```
void onCreate(..) {
    ...
    mLinearLayout = getViewById(R.id.your_layout);          
    mFrameLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(myOnGlobalLayoutListener);
}

OnGlobalLayoutListener myOnGlobalLayoutListener =new OnGlobalLayoutListener(){
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        if (!mFlag) {
            mFlag = true;
            mLinearLayout.setLayoutParams(mLinearLayout.getWidth(), mLinearLayout.getWidth() / 2));
        }
    }
};
```

Sorry for my english!
Hope it will help you!